# how to draw charts with json file data in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

my json.data file is in the same directory as my index.html file. data.json file looks like this:

```
  {
 data:
    [
          [1369540800000,20]
    ]
}
```

when I do:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 4));
```

I get this back, so I get the values. Still dont know what is wrong.

```
{
   "data":[
    [
      1369540800000,
          10
        ],
        [
          1369541700000,
          20
    ]
      ]
}
```

my html file including java script to build the charts is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <title>HIGHTCHARTS</title>

                <style>

                        body
                        {
                                font: 10px arial;
                        }

                </style>

             <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
             <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript">

                $(function () {
                            var chart;
                            $.getJSON('data.json', function(jsonData) {
                                chartOptions.series = jsonData;
                                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions);
                            });

                            var chartOptions = {
                                chart: {
                                    renderTo: 'container'
                                },
                                xAxis: {
                                    type: 'datetime'
                                },

                                series: []
                            };
                        });
                </script>


        </head>

        <body>
               <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
        </body>

</html>
```

I see the chart title but I dont see any charts or data points. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what I had to do to make it work:

```
<script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>


     <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
                var options = {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        type: 'area'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'datetime'
                    },
                series: [{}]
                };

            $.getJSON('dude.json', function(data) {
                options.series[0].data = data;
                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });

        });
     </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your data is not in the right format.  Familiarize yourself with how to format data for Highcharts.

These may help:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data
- http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocesssing-data-from-a-file

Notably:

1) your dates must be either a javascript time stamp (epoch time, in milliseconds), or a date.Utc declaration

2) your structure needs to be like:

```
[[date, value],[date,value],[date,value]]
```

Comment: @jbringgs, I did exactly that, I still dont see any data points on the chart. [[1369540800,14.84],[1369540800,14.84]]

Comment: Multiply timestamps by 1000 - in Javascript timestamp should be in milliseconds.

Comment: @PawełFus, I multiplied ith by 1000, I still dont see any data points on the chart. my data.json file looks like this: [[1369540800000,10],[1369541700000,20],[1369542600000,50],[1369543500000,45],[1369544400000,45],[1369545300000,100]]

Comment: You need to make sure you are adding the data at the right level of the series object.  Your final product needs to be "series:[{ data: [[date,value],[date,value]] }]"

Comment: @jlbriggs, I just updated my json data in the post. It still not working. I just need to get this right.

Comment: If so, use: `series: [{ data: json.data}]`